# How to add my new plugin to smarty?

Tags: plugins, smarty

I want to add a `SmartyFilter` class to smarty, but where to put the file so smarty can find it automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Smarty comes with a `plugins` subdirectory. Throw your script in there and smarty will find your plugin in there.

You can extend that path by adding other directories to `$smarty->plugins_dir[]`

```
$smarty->plugins_dir[] = 'includes/my_smarty_plugins';
```

If your plugins are dependant on each other you may want to require a plugin yourself by doing:

```
require_once $smarty->_get_plugin_filepath('function', 'html_options');
```

This would load a plugin in `plugin_dir` with the name `function.html_options.php`.

Answer (score 0):

copy and paste theme into "plugins" sub directory in main smarty folder, the file name must be leading with function.filename.php

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of Smarty, you have a method to add a plugin folder:

```
// Add a folder of plugins
$smarty->addPluginsDir('./plugins_1/');

// Check what plugins folders are registered
var_dump($smarty->getPluginsDir());

/* DUMP:
array(2) {
  [0]=>string() "./plugins/"
  [1]=> string() "./plugins_1/"
}
*/
```

For more information, you can read [the addPluginsDir() documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.add.plugins.dir.tpl).